# Перенос лицензии OEM windows 10 на другой комьютер

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-7, лицензирование, key

Имеется OEM ключ Windows 7, который шел в комплекте с системным блоком. Позже, эта система была успешно обновлена до Windows 10 через автоматическое обновление.

В данный момент заказан новый компьютер. Как я могу мигрировать на него лицензионную версию Windows 10?

Мнения разнятся, кто-то говорит что это невозможно, кто-то что это можно сделать по телефону. Где же истина?

Спасибо!

Comment: Скорей всего по телефону получится. По правилам лицензирования ОЕМ нельзя переносить на другой компьютер. В активации отправляются данные устройства. Как следствие лицензия слетает даже при апгрейде оборудования (типа матери или процессора). В таких случаях обычно активируется по телефону. Может сразу перейти на автомат, а может сотрудник задать пару дежурных вопросов и переключить на автомат. На 10-ке не проверял, но на предыдущих версиях процедура была такая

Comment: Спасибо. А как наиболее корректно озвучить свою проблему? Или просто сказать что обновил комплектующие, и теперь не могу легализоваться?

Comment: Ну да. Замена запчастей после ремонта. Вопрос в другом. При приобретении компьютера с ОЕМ-лицензией, он должен был быть принят на баланс организации. Эти документы обычно проверяют в случае проверки лицензионных требований. Соответственно будет сложно доказать, что новый компьютер - это пересобранный старый. И доказывать придется не майкрософту

Comment: @Dmitry Kozlov а из чего следует, что автор вопроса покупал компьютер на организацию ???

Comment: Опыт показывает, что частные лица редко заморачиваются с лицензированием)))

Answer (score 3):

Добрый день!

ОЕМ лицензия НЕ ПРЕДПОЛАГАЕТ миграцию на другой компьютер. Как только OEM Windows была установлена на компьютер, она становится его неотъемлемой частью.

К тому же не путайте юридическую правомочность и техническую возможность операции "переклеить наклейку и активировать виндовс" !!!!

Все необходимые сведения об ОЕМ лицензиях даны на сайте Microsoft по [ссылке](https://www.microsoft.com/OEM/ru/licensing/sblicensing/Pages/licensing_faq.aspx#fbid=9pDrnIdKcRP?hashlink=faq5)